# Access AWS session token from profile with DefaultCredentialsProvider

Tags: aws-sts, aws-sdk-java-2.0, aws-credentials

My AWS profile in `~/.aws/credentials` contains session credentials created by STS.

```
[default]
aws_session_token=XXX
aws_access_key_id=XXX
aws_secret_access_key=XXX
```

I am trying to access these credentials using the AWS SDK Java v2

Using the `DefaultCredentialsProvider` or `ProfileCredentialsProvider` finds them, but the returned object is of type `AwsCredentials` rather than `AwsSessionCredentials` which doesn't include the session token, only the access key ID and secret access key.

Is there any way to retrieve the full session credentials?

Answer (score 1):

AwsCredentials is an interface.

```
public interface AwsCredentials {
    String accessKeyId();
    String secretAccessKey();
}
```

and its implemented by AwsBasicCredentials and AwsSessionCredentials.

Based on whether session token is set or not, proper class will be returned to you when one calls resolveCredentials() API.

Answer (score 1):

Below code can be used to get the credential details

```
BasicSessionCredentials basicSessionCredentials = (BasicSessionCredentials) new ProfilesConfigFile().getCredentials(profile);
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using AwsCredentials/AwsSessionCredentials why dont you like to use **Aws4PresignerParams** it will gives you all three params (aws_session_token,aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key).